# Split array in three equal sum subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Write a solution for the input array
which elements of the array are sorted into three
groups.
The sum of the elements of each group would
should be approximately equal.

Example 1: [7,5,3,1,2,3]
Result: [7] // 7, [5,2] //7, [3,3,1] // 7

I managed to do it when there is sum which can be divided in three equal parts. My question is how to upgrade code so it works in cases when sum is not equal or when some element of array is lager than divided sum?
Here is my code so far:

```
    var input=document.getElementById('niz').value;
    var arr=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input[i]!=" " && !isNaN(input[i])){
            arr.push(input[i]);
        }
        
        
    }
    console.log(arr);
    var n=arr.length;
    var status=true;
    if(n<3){
        status=false;
    }
    else{
        var sum = 0;
        var auxiliary = 0;
        var i=0;
        var j=0;
        //calculate sum of elements
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        var point = Array(2).fill(0);
        if (sum % 3 == 0)
        {
            // Find that three equal subarray exists in given array
            for (i = 0; i < n && j < 2; ++i)
            {
                // Add current element into auxiliary variable
                auxiliary += arr[i];
                if (auxiliary == parseInt(sum / 3))
                {
                    point[j] = i + 1;
                    // Set zero sum
                    auxiliary = 0;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (j == 2)
            {
                // When equal three subarray exist
                j = 0;
                // Print the elements of subarray
                for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                {
                    if (j < 2 && point[j] == i)
                    {
                            
                        j++;
                    }
                    
                    console.log(arr[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                status=false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            status=false;
        }

    }if(status!=true){
        console.log("\n is is not possible")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you in the same class as this guy? [Separating array into 3 parts with near the same sum in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72596702/2743458)

Comment: What is 'approximately equal'? do you have a threshold? If one value is larger, then it will set the threshold for you... (definitely looks like a duplicate, but unable to flag due to no accepted answer)

Comment: @plichard threshold is supposed to be sum/3 so each element has almost equal sum, so the problem is what to do when the sum is not dividable by 3, so sum%3!=0.

Comment: The ideal is sum/3, but the threshold would the amount it can deviate from sum/3 and still be considered 'approximately equal'.